# Spring JNDIDataSourceLookup failed to lookup for JNDSI datasource in Glassfish?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, glassfish, jndi

I get an error whenever I try to deploy my Spring war application to Glassfish server ( with Glassfish 4 and 5 ):

However, everything is okay if I run the application straight from the Eclipse. My project is Maven project, I just right click the projeck and the choose Run As -> Run On server

Here's my glassfish-resources.xml, its located in the WEB-INF folder and its included in the deployment ( I've verified it )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_pos_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="pos"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="root"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pos?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/pos" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_pos_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

The beans in my RootContextConfiguration class:

```
@Bean
public DataSource springJpaDataSource()
{
    JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return lookup.getDataSource("java:app/pos");
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
{
    Map<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action",
            "none");

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    factory.setDataSource(this.springJpaDataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("my.package.entity");
    factory.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
    factory.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
    factory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return factory;
}
```

The error is as below:

> "Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in class sunwell.pos.service.config.RootContextConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sunwell.pos.service.config.RootContextConfiguration.entityManagerFactoryBean()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springJpaDataSource' defined in class sunwell.pos.service.config.RootContextConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource sunwell.pos.service.config.RootContextConfiguration.springJpaDataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'java:app/pos'; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext] available at JNDI location [java:app/pos] is not assignable to [javax.sql.DataSource]. Please see server.log for more details."

EDIT:

I have found that during deployment, the jndi name must be prefixed with `jdbc` or something after the namespace, example: `java:app/jdbc/pos` and not just `java:app/pos`, however I'm not sure why I can run it with eclipse even without the `jdbc` prefix and in JEE application I also can reference the jndi name in persistence like this `<jta-data-source>java:app/pos</jta-data-source>`.

So bottom line is this problem only occurs during Spring war deployment. And the solution is you need to prefix the jndi name after the namespace with `jdbc` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this

In the glassfish-resources.xml,

change `jndi-name="java:app/pos"` to `jndi-name="jdbc/pos"`

And in the springJpaDataSource() method,

change `return lookup.getDataSource("java:app/pos");`

to `return lookup.getDataSource("java:app/jdbc/pos");`

However, I still don't understand why does specifying `java:app/pos` in both of glassfish-resources.xml and springJpaDataSource work if I run it from Eclipse but not if I really deploy it, and also in JEE application I can give jndi-name to `java:app/pos` in glassfish-resources.xml and reference it in the persistence.xml like this `<jta-data-source>java:app/pos</jta-data-source>`